# How to Handle null result of a Query using Jena API in Java

Tags: java, servlets, jena

I am using Jena API. Every thing works fine with me, except when query match (i.e. result of Query is null) is not found in an Ontology Model. Then nothing is displayed in Browser using servlet, and null pointer exception is displayed at console. i.e given below. Can anyone guide me how to handle this null pointer exception? thank you.

```
Jun 04, 2014 3:37:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [main.DevInsta] in context with path [/FMOnt] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.DevInsta.doGet(DevInsta.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Two additional things will assist greatly in answering this question: (1) The query that is failing (2) The code that is invoking the query (especially at/around line 71). As you allude to in your question, the exception isn't happening in Jena's code (it bottoms out in your `DevInsta.doGet` method), so there is some mismanagement of results. We can only give vague/general solutions if we don't have the additional context.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial Solution**

At the time of this answer, the query string used in this question is not posted, nor is the code which is used around where the `NullPointerException` occurs. This is a first-pass at assisting with the answer.

My usual source of a `NullPointerException` when working with a `QueryExecution` comes from one of two places:

*Aggregates*

If your query is using `GROUP BY x`, but your data doesn't bind anything to `x`, you can end up with a `ResultSet` that looks like the following:

```
---------------
|  ?x  |  ?y  |
---------------
|      |      |
---------------
```

You can get an unexpected `true` result from `hasNext()`, and then a subsequent `NullPointerException` when attempting to retrieve elements. The solution is, for aggregate queries, to test if the first result's expected bindings contain any `null` values as well.

*Optional*

If your query includes an optional block, then it may not get bound for a particular solution, and you need to test for it:

```
SELECT ?x ?y {
   ?x rdf:type urn:ExampleClass .
   OPTIONAL { ?x urn:p ?y }
}
```

When you iterate over `QuerySolution` objects, the value returned by getting a variable may be `null`, and you need to account for it in your code.

**WebService Help**

One thing which I would suggest, if your `ResultSet` isn't very large, is to use a `ResultSetRewindable` (provided by `ResultSetFactory.copyResults`). In your web application, if you use a decent logging library, you can test things like `logger.isDebugEnabled()`. If it is, you can print a diagnostic value for the query using `ResultSetFormatter`. This can be *extremely* useful when attempting to understand why your rendering of a query is giving you unexpected results:

```java
final QueryExecution exec = ...;
final ResultSetRewindable r = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(exec.execSelect());
exec.close();
// Assuming slf4j
if( logger.isDebugEnabled() ) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream results = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ResultSetFactory.out(results,r);
    r.reset();
    logger.debug("Rendering query solution:\n{}", results);
}
// Continue on like you normally would
```

If you don't want to do this in general (maybe `doGet` is called far too often and/or your results are too large and/or this is a complex system where the error happens rarely), then you can always put a `try{..}catch(..){..}`-block around where the exception is occurring, and only print a copy of the results when this particular exception is triggered.